# My route is not firing, should this work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

For my administration area I have created a special route.  I did this so my urls look cleaner, and it avoids the problem of me having 2 controllers with the same name.

Example:  I have a UserController and another AdminUserController for the admin site of the application.

I don't want URL's like:

```
http://www.example.com/user/...
http://www.example.com/admin/adminuser/...
```

**I want the admin url's to look like:**

```
http://www.example.com/admin/user/...
```

Now to get this url structure, I tried this:

I named my admin controller:  AdminUserController

Then my route looks like:

```
routes.Add(new Route("admin/Admin{controller}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
  Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Admin", action = "index", Id=""});
});
```

Can this work? (the route is currently not working)

I made sure to have this route above the generic route.

**Update**

**I want all my admin urls to be prefixed with the /admin/ folder, so:**

```
www.example.com/admin/user
www.example.com/admin/settings
www.example.com/admin/articles
```

and non-admin are like:

```
www.example.com/user
www.example.com/articles
```

Comment: This is a good tool for routing issues with asp.net mvc, http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, that won't work.

Keep in mind that we append "Controller" to the URL part passed in for {controller}. Thus the URL that would work there is:

/admin/AdminAdminUser/

Try this instead.

```
routes.Add(new Route("admin/user/admin/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
  Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "AdminUser", action = "index", Id=""})
});
```

I'm assuming the AdminUser controller is a special case and you don't have other controllers that start with /user/. If you did, an alternate approach is to rename AdminUserController back to AdminController. Then:

```
routes.Add(new Route("admin/user/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
  Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Admin", action = "index", Id=""}),
  Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Admin|Other|Other2"})
});
```

Here i'm using a constraint to limit which controllers this particular route applies to.

BTW, I'd recommend using the MapRoute extension methods. They make for much less verbose route registration.

Comment: I want www.example.com/admin/user and www.example.com/user to work.  One controller is AdminUserController and UserController.  is that what you responded too?  becaues your 2nd route is admin/user/{controller}...  I have many admin controllers, so I don't want to hardcode. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
routes.Add(new Route("admin/Admin{controller}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
{
  Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Admin", action = "index", Id=""});
});
```

will force you to have "admin/AdminUser" ...

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "admin/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "User", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

will allow you to have an admin controller with an action User

---

More accurately what you are looking to do is create an area (use MVC 2)

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/10/13/asp-net-mvc2-preview-2-areas-and-routes.aspx

should give you what you want...

Comment: you have 
admin/Admin{controller}
which which means two admins before it starts to find the controller name

Comment: hmm, but I want a UserController and a AdminUserController (I will also have other AdminXXXController's).

Comment: you want all the admin controllers to start /admin/ ??

Answer (score 0):

With 1.0 the only way to  do this is :

Using 1.0 the only way to do this is to map each controller individually using

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminUserRoute",                     // Route name
            "admin/user/{action}/{id}",           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "AdminUser", action = "Index", id = "" } 
    );

   routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminWorkRoute",                    // Route name
            "admin/work/{action}/{id}",          // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "AdminWork", action = "Index", id = "" }                
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an implementation of IRouteHandler that will intercept the requested controller and append "admin" to the front

```
public class AdminRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    private readonly IRouteHandler _mvcHandler = new MvcRouteHandler();
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var values = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
        if(values.ContainsKey("controller"))
            values["controller"] = "Admin" + values["controller"];
        return _mvcHandler.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

And use that when registering your route, replacing `Home` with whatever controller that *admin/* should direct you to. Leaving `Home` in default would map to `AdminHome` after passing through the `AdminRouteHandler`.

```
routes.Add(new Route("admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new AdminRouteHandler())
{
  Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "index",     Id=""});
});
```